# some elements of a forms are undefined in watch event of a form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Html Page with four input, I have put a watch on form in controller but inside this function one of my input fields is undefined.
All elements are defined in same way but only one is undefined.

I assume that watch on a form triggers only when form is completely ready and all the elements are constructed..

Here is HTML snippet:

```
<form name="hireform" class="form-horizontal form-main" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div data-ng-if="isEligible()">
            <label for="inputAcknowledgeDate" xyz-required class="control-label col-xs-6 col-md-3">Gave Information Date</label>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <input type="text" id="inputAcknowledgeDate" name="inputAcknowledgeDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ng-pattern="hireUtil.datesRegex" ng-model="hireData.screeningAckDate" ng-disabled="isGaveInformationDateReadOnly || postHire" xyz-date-picker date-check="checkGaveOfferDates()"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" data-ng-show="isEligible()">
        <label for="offerDate" xyz-required class="control-label col-xs-6 col-md-3">Job Offer Date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="offerDate" name="offerDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ng-model="hireData.offerExtensionDate" ng-pattern="hireUtil.datesRegex" ng-disabled="isOfferDateReadOnly || postHire" xyz-date-picker date-check="checkGaveOfferDates()">
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputHireDate" xyz-required class="control-label col-xs-6 col-md-3">Employment Hire Date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="inputHireDate" name="inputHireDate" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ng-pattern="hireUtil.datesRegex"  ng-model="hireData.hireDate" ng-disabled="isHireDateReadOnly || postHire" xyz-date-picker date-check="checkHireStartDates()">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputStartDate" xyz-required class="control-label col-xs-6 col-md-3">Employment Start Date</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="inputStartDate" name="inputStartDate" required class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" ng-pattern="hireUtil.datesRegex" ng-model="hireData.actualStartDate" ng-disabled="isStartDateReadOnly|| postHire"
                   xyz-date-picker date-check="checkHireStartDates()">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 hire-submit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" ng-disabled="(isSubmitButtonDisabled)" ng-click="processHire()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <span class="cancel">
            <button id="cancel-button" xyz-button="link" ng-click="closeSlide()" icon="times" size="lg" type="button" class="btn btn-direct lg">
                <span class="ng-scope"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Js code:

```
$scope.$watch('hireform', function(theForm) {
    if(hireform) {
        if($scope.parameterMap[Constants.gaveInfoDateParameter] == null) {
            $scope.isGaveInformationDateReadOnly = false;   
            notifyDates(Constants.gaveInfoDate,$scope.hireData.screeningAckDate);
        }

        if($scope.parameterMap[Constants.offerDateParameter] == null) {
            $scope.isOfferDateReadOnly = false;
            notifyDates(Constants.offerDate,$scope.hireData.offerExtensionDate);
        }
        if($scope.parameterMap[Constants.hireDateParameter] == null) {
            $scope.isHireDateReadOnly = false;
            notifyDates(Constants.hireDate,$scope.hireData.hireDate);
        }                                                   
        if($scope.parameterMap[Constants.startDateParameter] == null) {
            $scope.isStartDateReadOnly = false;
            notifyDates(Constants.startDate,$scope.hireData.actualStartDate);
        }
    }
 });


var notifyDates = function(dateName,dateValue) {
    for (var key in $scope.parameterMap)
    {
        var dependencyExpression = $scope.parameterMap[key];
        if(dependencyExpression != null) {
            if (getDependentDateType(dependencyExpression)==dateName){
                switch (key) {
                    case Constants.gaveInfoDateParameter:
                        $scope.hireform.inputAcknowledgeDate.$setViewValue(evaluateDateExpression(dateValue,dependencyExpression));
                        $scope.hireform.inputAcknowledgeDate.$render();
                        break;
                    case Constants.offerDateParameter:
                        $scope.hireform.offerDate.$setViewValue(evaluateDateExpression(dateValue,dependencyExpression));
                        $scope.hireform.offerDate.$render();
                        break;
                    case Constants.hireDateParameter:
                        $scope.hireform.inputHireDate.$setViewValue(evaluateDateExpression(dateValue,dependencyExpression));
                        $scope.hireform.inputHireDate.$render();
                        break;
                    case Constants.startDateParameter:
                        $scope.hireform.inputStartDate.$setViewValue(evaluateDateExpression(dateValue,dependencyExpression));
                        $scope.hireform.inputStartDate.$render();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In `notifyDates` `$scope.hireform.inputAcknowledgeDate` is undefined whereas rest of all are valid object.

Comment: please add relevant code..

Comment: You must add your code for us to help you. Maybe it's just a typo but we can't tell.

Comment: Please look if it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the inconsistent use of `ng-show` and `ng-if` in your HTML.

[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

> The `ngShow` directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the `ngShow` attribute

[`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

> The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an `{expression}`. If the expression assigned to `ngIf` evaluates to a `false` value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Because of the difference, the first block, where you use `ng-if`, is never rendered at all if the condition is `false`, which in turn leads to the form element being `undefined`.  In the other block, where `ng-show` is used, the form element is still rendered, but hidden, and thus is not `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was really helpful.
Changing ng-if to ng-show does the work, but I have one doubt, my expression iselligible() always return true, even I tried replacing expression to 'true' but still get the same same issue. Does it mean control under ng-if rendered after watch event trigers?
Or How can I get it working if I want to use ng-If?

Comment: Indeed, you intuition is correct, ng-if renders a *clone* of the original HTML *after* the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Do you have any idea How can I find this element if I keep ng-if behaviour? I googled thi and found that ng-if create a new child scope but I didnt find how to find this element in child scope..

Comment: I'm not really clear on exactly what your code is trying to do here as I read through it again.  It looks like you are trying to set the value on a form to the value of another element;  I think you might actually be doing this backwards.  Instead of setting the form element to a value, you should just be manipulating the value of the `ng-bind` variable, which isn't dependent on the form.